# Updating an app from xcode instead of fresh install

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game for iOS and I am testing it on my iPhone. Is there any way I can update an old version of a game when testing it (installing it via xcode). It seems that xcode always installs a fresh copy on a device. So I want to install the game, play it for some time (reach some scores, store some data,...) and then update it with a new version from xcode (without loosing data).

Regards, L

Comment: I never lose data when I deploy an update from Xcode. How are you storing your data?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the current state of the current version of your game, using NSUserDefaults, and then load the game state back (if it is saved) every time you launch the game. [This tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-working-with-nsuserdefaults--mobile-6039) is old but contains all the basics.